Compilation error: 'class Firebase_ESP_Client' has no member named 'set'
I uploded my ESP32's code and I git this error :
'Compilation error: 'class Firebase_ESP_Client' has no member named 'set'; did you mean 'reset'?'
knowing that I used this code :
  Firebase.set(firebaseData, "/Air/temperature", temperature);
  Firebase.set(firebaseData, "/Air/humidity", humidity);
  Firebase.set(firebaseData, "/Air/timestamp", formattedTime);

Any suggestions for solving this issue please?
I attempt to update values in a Firebase database using an instance of the Firebase_ESP_Client class. Each line updates a specific key in the Firebase database with a new value.
Sends the humidity/temperature/formattedTime value to the /Air/humidity;/Air/temperature;/Air/timestamp path in Firebase

Maybe show us a bit more code here - where is Firebase defined.
